# how to create a new variant in bjam

Tags: bjam, boost-build

I've tried reading the documentation but it is rather impenetrable so I'm hoping someone may have a simple answer. I want to define a new 'variant', based on 'debug', which just adds some macro definitions to the compiler command line, eg "-DSOMEMACRO".  I think I may be able to do this as a "sub-variant" of debug, or else just define a new variant copying 'debug', but I'm not even sure where to do this.  It looks like feature.jam in $BOOST_BUILD_DIR/build may be the place.  Perhaps what I really want is simply a new 'feature' but it's still not clear to me exactly what I need to do and where, and I don't know if a 'feature' allows me to direct the build products to a different directory to the 'debug' build.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. (In case you're wondering, I have to use bjam since it has been adopted as our corporate standard.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but there's a number of possibilities.

A. You always want to compile with the SOMEMACRO macro defined.  In which case, in the Jamfile for your project add

```
project
  : requirements # These are requirements for this project
      # If compiling debug, define SOMEMACRO
      <variant>debug:<define>SOMEMACRO
  : usage-requirements
      # These are requirements projects using this project must have
      <variant>debug:<define>SOMEMACRO
  ;
```

If you need SOMEMACRO always defined, you can remove the `<variant>debug:` condition.  If you need to set other flags you can use `<cflags>`, `<cxxflags>`, and `<linkflags>` as appropriate.

B. You want a quick switch to turn on your flags/define, perhaps by default, perhaps not, and builds with it on are not compatible with builds with it off.  In which case you want a feature.

```
import feature ;
feature.feature steves-feature : off on
  : composite propagated link-incompatible ;
feature.compose <steves-feature>on : <define>SOMEMACRO ;
```

The `feature.feature` rule defines a feature called `<steves-feature>` with two possible values and three properties.  `composite` means it's a feature composed of other features (in this case `<define>SOMEMACRO`).  `propagated` means that any targets that include a target with this feature set will also have this feature set.  and `link-incompatible` means targets with `<steves-feature>on` can't be combined with targets with `<steves-feature>off`.  (As a result, bjam will put the created files under a directory named `steves-feature-on` or `steves-feature-off` if this feature is set by any target.)

This feature can be used just like the `<define>` feature used in the project rule in the above section.  (You can even add it to a `default-build` section of the project rule.)

Note that you can also set features from the command line: `bjam steves-feature=on`.

C. You want a full variant.  I think the idea is if you have a few common build configurations with a bunch of different features that should be set together.  Well, if you've already created the feature as above, this is now easy.

```
variant steves-debug : debug : <steves-feature>on ;
```

This variant will be the same as the `debug` variant but with the additional feature `<steves-feature>on`.

I've never used the `variant` rule, so it might need to be imported from somewhere.  Also, you might be able to do

```
variant steves-debug : debug : <define>SOMEMACRO ;
```

but I don't know if bjam will create the directory structure or not.  (It probably will.)

Comment: Thanks, case B or perhaps C is what I'm looking for, I'll try B first since it is simplest. Thanks for a very detailed explanation.

Comment: If this works, you should click on the check mark next to the answer to mark it as answered.  That way others know the question is answered.  And I get some credit. :-)  (You haven't done accepted answers on your previous questions either.)

Comment: Apologies, I have now selected it, I'm still getting used to the protocol.

Comment: if steves-variant behavior can be summed up in one line do you know if there is a way to define it on a _single_ target ? so i dont have to copy/paste multiple targets for my "build variants" ? like `lib steveslib_on : ...files... : <linker stuff> <steves-variant> on ...whatever.. ;` this way i need 2 lib for each variant , which can be verbose